# Render a view based on the conditional statement in Spring

Tags: spring

I am kind of new to Spring. I am trying to render a view based on the the value returned from `DBDAOImplementation` class using a conditional if statement inside `processController`. I am trying to return `successuseraddstatus` jsp file for success scenarios and `faileduseraddstatus` jsp file for failed scenarios.

ProcessController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adduserstatus", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Process process,ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("fname", process.getFname());
    model.addAttribute("lname", process.getLname());
    model.addAttribute("email", process.getEmail());
    model.addAttribute("phone", process.getPhone());

    ApplicationContext context = 
         new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

    DBDAOImp dbd = 
         (DBDAOImp)context.getBean("JDBCTemplate");

    dbd.createuser(process.getFname(), process.getLname(), process.getEmail(), process.getPhone());

    if (true){ //This is where I am having trouble
        return "successuseraddstatus";
    } 
    return "faileduseraddstatus";
}
```

DBDAOImplementation.java:

```
@Override
public Boolean createuser(String fname, String lname, String email, String phone) {

    isExists(email);

    if (isExists==false){

        String SQL = "insert into USERS (user_id,f_name,l_name,creation_date,email,phone) values (seq_users.nextval,?,?,sysdate,?,?)";

        jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL, fname,lname,email,phone);
        System.out.println("Created Record");
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What trouble? That should work fine.

Comment: What is the error or problem in this case?

Comment: Why are you creating a new `ApplicationContext` on each request?

Comment: @ Martin - I removed ApplicationContext on each request

Comment: @ Balwinder - I was getting DeadCode for the else condition when I tried using above mentioned code. Below if condition works.

Answer (score 0):

Below if condition works. But I am not too sure if this is the right approach.

ProcessController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adduserstatus", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Process process,ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("fname", process.getFname());
    model.addAttribute("lname", process.getLname());
    model.addAttribute("email", process.getEmail());
    model.addAttribute("phone", process.getPhone());

     DBDAOImp dbd = 
         (DBDAOImp)context.getBean("JDBCTemplate");


     if (dbd.createuser(process.getFname(), process.getLname(), process.getEmail(), process.getPhone())){
      return "useraddstatus";
      } else {
          return "faileduseraddstatus";
      }
}
```